# Label at the beginning of a D3 axis

Tags: d3.js, label, timeline, axis-labels

How would I make d3 put "Tue 20" to the left of "Wed 21"?

http://jsfiddle.net/robdodson/KWRxW/

```
var data = [
             {"date":"2012-03-20","total":3},
             {"date":"2012-03-21","total":8},
             {"date":"2012-03-22","total":2},
             {"date":"2012-03-23","total":10},
             {"date":"2012-03-24","total":3},
             {"date":"2012-03-25","total":20},
             {"date":"2012-03-26","total":12}
           ];

var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left:40},
    width = 600,
    height = 500;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([
              new Date(data[0].date),
              d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)
            ])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })])
    .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(8);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left')
    .tickPadding(8);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

svg.selectAll('.chart')
    .data(data)
   .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date)); })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
         return height - margin.top - margin.bottom -
                (height - margin.top - margin.bottom - y(d.total))
    })
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('height', function(d) {
         return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - y(d.total)
    });

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine for me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff do you see "Tue 20" on the x axis? I tried multiple browsers.

Comment: Yes. Google Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Strange.. I see it in an old Firefox browser only - not Chrome (incl. Canary), FF 19/20, Opera 12, Safari (incl. iOS). This calls for some investigating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened due to inconsistencies in date managing. By using UTC dates and the d3 date functions the issue will not occur.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1234